# Using bash script to iterate through comma separated directories

Tags: bash, shell, debian

I'm using a linux shell script **(Debian)** in order to create backups of certain directories.

It's already working for one directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRNAME="directory1"

# This is the backup
tar cfv "_backups/NEW.tar" $DIRNAME > /dev/null 2>&1

...

# This is the restore
rm -rf $DIRNAME
tar xfv ...
```

Now I need to do backup & restore for multiple comma separated directories. I.e.:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRNAMES="directory1,directory2,directory3,..."
```

**Question:** How can I trigger the `tar cfv` command in order to pack the directories in `$DIRNAMES` into one tar and how can I trigger `rm -rf` so it removes these directories before the tar extraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming** none of the directories has any whitespace in the name, just translate the commas to spaces, and take advantage of the shell's word splitting.

```
dirs=${DIRNAMES//,/ }

set -f     # disable glob expansion for safety

# This is the backup
tar cfv "_backups/NEW.tar" $dirs > /dev/null 2>&1     # do not quote $dirs

# This is the restore
rm -rf $dirs             # do not quote $dirs
tar xfv ...
```

Comment: Yes, they don't have white spaces. And your solution works! Thanks!